# How to color months in sap.m.DatePicker?

Tags: css, datepicker, sapui5

I am using `sap.m.DatePicker`, I want to change color of some months (background color of month item).

[image]

I tried to change background color of `sapUiCalItem` in `style.css` file. I added this class to my CSS file but this changes the colors of all datePicekers that I have.

```
.sapUiCalItem{
  background-color: #920000;
}
```

Then I added class to my DatePicker

```
<m:DatePicker
  id="datePickerId"
  class="datePickerClass"
  value="{period}"
  valueFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
  displayFormat="MMMM yyyy"
  change="onChangeDate"/>
```

and changed CSS like this

```
.datePickerClass.sapUiCalItem{
  background-color: #920000 !important;
}
```

also, I tried to add class like this

```
self.getView().byId("datePickerId").addStyleClass("datePickerClass");
```

But that didn't work either. Is there any way of coloring this months in `sap.m.DatePicker` ?

Comment: It's no use to add classes to the DatePicker instance as months are shown in a separate popup which technically is outside <div> tag of the datepicker (actually it is closer to the head of the generated HTML). There is a "protected" property of DatePicker, this._oCalendar, technically you can access months with it. But, well, it is protected

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. You can try to subclass MonthPicker and write a new MonthPickerRenderer, then subclass Calendar to use your new MonthPicker, then subclass DatePicker to use your new Calendar.

Comment: Also, if you "hardcode" colors, you may face issues when the user changes the theme. It's better to use semantic colors in this case (https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/how-to-use-semantic-colors/)

Comment: Which UI5 version you are using?

Comment: @inizio I am using 1.68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by attaching the event to the month button `attachPressButton1`.
Once the month layout is opened, the corresponding months will be highlighted.

Assuming you know the months to the colored like
`var oMonths = { 0:"Red", 6:"Green", 11: "yellow"};`. Where 0 - Jan, 1 - Feb... 11 - Dec. Modify this `oMonths` object and the corresponding month color as per your requirement.

**view.XML**

```
<DatePicker id="dpColoufulMonths" placeholder="Enter Date ..."/>
```

**Controller.js**

```
var oDP = this.byId("dpColoufulMonths");
if (oDP) {          
    oDP._openPopup = function() {
        if (!this._oPopup) {
            return;
        }
        this._oPopup.setAutoCloseAreas([this.getDomRef()]);
        var k = sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock;
        var A;
        if (this.getTextAlign() == sap.ui.core.TextAlign.End) {
            A = k.EndBottom + '-4';
            this._oPopup.open(0, k.EndTop, A, this, null, 'fit', true);
        } else {
            A = k.BeginBottom + '-4';
            this._oPopup.open(0, k.BeginTop, A, this, null, 'fit', true);
        }
        //Custom implementation for color update
        var oDatePopup = this._oPopup.getContent();
        if (oDatePopup) {
            var oDatePopupHdr = this._oPopup.getContent().mAggregations.header;
            var oMonths = { 0:"Red", 6:"Green", 11: "yellow"};
            if (oDatePopupHdr) {
                oDatePopupHdr.attachPressButton1(function(oEvent) { //Month textButton
                    for (var m in oMonths) {
                        var sMonthID = "#" + oDatePopup.mAggregations.monthPicker.sId + "-m" + m;
                        jQuery(sMonthID).css({"background-color" : oMonths[m]}); //inline styling 
                        //jQuery(sMonthID).addClass("month"+oMonths[m]);// Adding the style class and styled it in CSS file
                    }
                });
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]